# How do I store 3rd-party API data after user interaction?

Tags: api, database-design, architecture

The project that I'm currently on is consuming a large volume of 3rd-party information exposed via APIs. These datasets are constantly changing and in the order of millions of entries for each.

Users are to denote their favorites and recall that data when they need it. An example may be that the user wants to "bookmark" an inventory level to their "analyze later" list.

My current thinking is that during actions like searching users are presented with "live" data from the 3rd parties. If they flag something they're interested in I copy that data to a database I control. Subsequent views of that info are served from my database, not the 3rd party, since the 3rd party entry may change (or cease to exist entirely).

Is this good API practice? What object keys are sent to the client-facing application on search? The 3rd party keys? Or do I preprocess the results of a search and determine which items I have locally, thus returning local keys in those instances? Or do I completely abstract the 3rd party sources and generate unique local keys for every returned item, which is then subsequently used if someone saves [that seems REALLY heavy, tho]? Or do I put that processing off and do the lookup as to whether something exists locally to after someone bookmarks something?

Comment: Don't forget to check with the 3rd part API FAQ / licensing terms.

Comment: Depending on your implementation environment, you might be able to get a caching library that fits your purposes. For example, every call that takes parms and returns data would first check the cache, using the parms as a key. A caching library would do some of the work, and also let you automate things like throwing out data that is older than some time-limit.

Also, The user should be aware that the data is not real-time.

Comment: How do you want to manage situations in which the 3-party data changes after it is copied into your system (synchronization)?